# Jinja2 set block not recognized in Django

Tags: python, django, tags, set, jinja2

I searched for 2 days before posting this, so I really hope its not a duplicate question.

I am building my first Django site and after getting into it I realized I'd rather have the power of jinja2.  I installed jinja2 to my virtual environment and made the necessary changes to django (see below).  However, django appears to be rendering the template with the standard django template engine instead of jinja2.

All of my code works as expected when using {% block content %} template content {% endblock content %}

Instead of block, I am trying to use {% set %} template content {% endset %} so that I can duplicate a template in base.html.  but I get this error:

```
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag on line 7: 'set'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
[05/Mar/2020 22:27:37] "GET /bge/ HTTP/1.1" 500 161659
```

I made the following changes to my project to try and make jinja2 work:

Settings:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2'
        ,
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/jinja2')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'environment': 'bge_app.jinja2.environment'
        },
    },
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')),],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

jinja2.py added to django_projects\bge\bge_app

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage
from django.urls import reverse
from jinja2 import Environment


def environment(**options):
    env = Environment(**options)
    env.globals.update({
        'static': staticfiles_storage.url,
        'url': reverse,
    })
    return env
```

This is the template at django_projects\bge\bge_app\templates\jinja2\dice.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}
<Title>Dice</Title>
{% endblock title %}

{% set dice_content %}
    <br/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <form class="m-3" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="input-group">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Add Die</button>
                {{ die_size_form.num_sides }}
                {{ die_size_form.active }}
              </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <a href="{% url 'roll_dice' %}">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info m-3">Roll Dice</button>
        </a>
        <table class="m-2 table-bordered text-center">
            <tr>
            <th class="p-2">Roll Sum</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {{ active_dice_sum }}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
        <table class="table-hover table-bordered text-center table-sm col-md-10">
            <tr>
                <th> Die Sides</th>
                <th> Die Status</th>
                <th> Roll Value</th>
                <th> Remove Die</th>
            </tr>
            {% for die in all_dice %}
                {% if die.active %}
                    {% if die.num_sides == 6 %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>D6 &nbsp;<img src="{% static '/images/dice/d6.png' %}" alt="D 6"></td>
                            <td><a href="{% url 'deactivate_die' die.id %}">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Active</button>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td> {{ die.roll_value }} </td>
                            <td><a href="{% url 'remove_die' die.id %}">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">X</button>
                            </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    {% else %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>D {{ die.num_sides }}</td>
                            <td><a href="{% url 'deactivate_die' die.id %}">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Active</button>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td> {{ die.roll_value }} </td>
                            <td><a href="{% url 'remove_die' die.id %}">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">X</button>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endif %}
                {% else %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>D {{ die.num_sides }}</td>
                        <td><a href="{% url 'activate_die' die.id %}">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Inactive</button>
                            </a>
                        <td> {{ die.roll_value }} </td>
                         <td><a href="{% url 'remove_die' die.id %}">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">X</button>
                        </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
{% endset dice_content %}
</div>
```

Here is base.html

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'index' %}"><i>Board Game Essentials</i></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'player_setup' %}">Player Setup</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'die_pool' %}">Dice</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'hp_tracker' %}">HP Tracker</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'score_calc' %}">Score Calculator</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

{#want to call set multiple times here#}

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you show base.html? What is "set" in  {% set dice_content %}?

Comment: I added base.html to my question.  I want to put everything in dice.html in a set block {set dice_content} dice.html stuff {endset dicecontent} and then call it over in base.html.  I could be using set wrong, but really I'm more concerned about django's inability to recognize the set tag because it means jinja2 isn't working.

Comment: you have not defined any block in base.html. I think you want <nav> in your all templates. I am writing anser to show what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**base.html** (some changes)

```
 <!doctype html>
    {% load static %}
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>{% block title %} {% endblock %}</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
<body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'index' %}"><i>Board Game Essentials</i></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'player_setup' %}">Player Setup</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'die_pool' %}">Dice</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'hp_tracker' %}">HP Tracker</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'score_calc' %}">Score Calculator</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    {#want to call set multiple times here#}
    {% block set %}


{% endblock %}
        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

**your templates**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Your webpage title {% endblock %}
{% block set %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <form class="m-3" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="input-group">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Add Die</button>
                {{ die_size_form.num_sides }}
                {{ die_size_form.active }}
              </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <a href="{% url 'roll_dice' %}">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info m-3">Roll Dice</button>
        </a>
        <table class="m-2 table-bordered text-center">
            <tr>
            <th class="p-2">Roll Sum</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {{ active_dice_sum }}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
        <table class="table-hover table-bordered text-center table-sm col-md-10">
            <tr>
                <th> Die Sides</th>
                <th> Die Status</th>
                <th> Roll Value</th>
                <th> Remove Die</th>
            </tr>
            {% for die in all_dice %}
                {% if die.active %}
                    {% if die.num_sides == 6 %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>D6 &nbsp;<img src="{% static '/images/dice/d6.png' %}" alt="D 6"></td>
                            <td><a href="{% url 'deactivate_die' die.id %}">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Active</button>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td> {{ die.roll_value }} </td>
                            <td><a href="{% url 'remove_die' die.id %}">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">X</button>
                            </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    {% else %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>D {{ die.num_sides }}</td>
                            <td><a href="{% url 'deactivate_die' die.id %}">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Active</button>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td> {{ die.roll_value }} </td>
                            <td><a href="{% url 'remove_die' die.id %}">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">X</button>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endif %}
                {% else %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>D {{ die.num_sides }}</td>
                        <td><a href="{% url 'activate_die' die.id %}">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Inactive</button>
                            </a>
                        <td> {{ die.roll_value }} </td>
                         <td><a href="{% url 'remove_die' die.id %}">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">X</button>
                        </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
</div>

 {% endblock %}
```

You define blocks in base templates `{% block your_block_name %}{% endblock %}`and use these blocks in child templates. Please let me know if you any error or don't understand the answer. Also you don't have to install anything (like jinja2). Django already supports this feature.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to look into my issue.  I am aware of how {block}{endblock} works, and in my question I stated that my code does indeed work when using blocks.  However, you cannot call the same block multiple times in base.html, which is what I want to do.  So for that I need to either use a macro or set, which is why I want to use jinja2.  I will also want some other jinja2 features later, but for now I'd really just like to see jinja2 being recognized in django.  I must be missing something obvious but I just don't see it.